# Tensorflow AttributeError: 'DataSet' object has no attribute 'image'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use Tensorflow for the first time

Here is my code that I got from a tutorial:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
learn = tf.contrib.learn
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

mnist = learn.datasets.load_dataset('mnist')
data = mnist.train.image //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
test_data = mnist.test.images
test_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype = np.int32)
```

I get this error at the line specified above `AttributeError: 'DataSet' object has no attribute 'image'`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MNIST `DataSet` object (implemented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/13f9309ccb063a58b0ce34aafc23f93a49e33733/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py)) does not have an `image` property, but it does have [an `images` property](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/13f9309ccb063a58b0ce34aafc23f93a49e33733/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L145). The following change should fix things:

```
data = mnist.train.images
```

Comment: It's the `s` at the end of `images`